# python capitalize() on a string starting with space

Tags: python, string, capitalize

I was using the capitalize method on some strings in Python and one of strings starts with a space:

```
phrase = ' Lexical Semantics'
```

`phrase.capitalize()` returns ' lexical semantics' all in lower case. Why is that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is the [listed behaviour](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize):

> Return a copy of the string with its first character capitalized and the rest lowercased.

The first character is a space, the space is unchanged, the rest lowercased.

If you want to make it all uppercase, see [`str.upper()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper), or [`str.title()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) for the first letter of every word.

```
>>> phrase = 'lexical semantics'
>>> phrase.capitalize()
'Lexical semantics'
>>> phrase.upper()
'LEXICAL SEMANTICS'
>>> phrase.title()
'Lexical Semantics'
```

Or, if it's just a problem with the space:

```
>>> phrase = ' lexical semantics'
>>> phrase.strip().capitalize()
'Lexical semantics'
```

Answer (score 3):

`.capitalize()` capitalises the first character ... which is a space :) Every other character gets lowercased.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the first character is a space, not a letter.